# Query objects newer then 24 hours

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So the way Snapchat has, they only show in story images/videos that are newer then 24 hours old. How can I do the same using this query code:

```
func queryStory(){
        let query = PFQuery(className: "myClass")
        query.whereKey("isPending", equalTo: false)
        query.limit = 1000
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (posts: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                // Success fetching objects

                for post in posts! {

                    if let imagefile = post["userFile"] as? PFFile {
                        self.userFile.append(post["userFile"] as! PFFile)
                        self.objID.append(post.objectId!)
                        self.createdAt.append(post.createdAt!)
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding:

```
var date: NSDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -172800)
query.whereKey("createdAt", greaterThan: date)
```

But this gave me 0 items.(My class has currently total 28 items). Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but 24 hours is 86400 seconds, not 172800.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format for 24 hours would be:

```
let date: NSDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -86400)
query.whereKey("createdAt", greaterThan: date)
```

How old are the files you are trying to query from Parse?

Comment: Oh, the files is a few days old i see.. Added a file now, and it seems to work now with your code! Thank you :)